# MSBuild and TFS 2010 not finding assemblies. QUOTES

Tags: tfsbuild

Question, "when I build locally in TFS 2010 my build builds fine and with no errors. When I attempt to build the same build through a build definition it errors out and says that it cannot find certain assemblies. I have tried specifying in the build definition -> process -> advanced settings, MSBuild Arguments /p:ReferencePath="C:\mypath\assemblies"

SOLVED. Lose the quotes, it should be  /p:ReferencePath=C:\mypath\assemblies
The MSBuild ReferencePath does not appear to handles QUOTES!

Whew!

Comment: please can you mark this as answered, ta